# Hide '0' values (zero counts) in plots utilizing geom_count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use `geom_count()` from the `ggplot2` library to overlay the `count` (blue) on top of the `total number` (gray) for each dataset split by weeks (see example dataset and plot below). Sometimes, the count value is '0' (here: in **DS1, week 3**).

```
# sample dataset
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(dataset = paste0("DS",rep(1:4, each = 5)),
                week = paste0("Week ",rep(1:4,5)),
                count = c(sample(0:50, 20, replace = TRUE)),
                total = rep(50,20)) 

> df
   dataset   week count total
1      DS1 Week 1     3    50
2      DS1 Week 2    38    50
3      DS1 Week 3     0    50
4      DS1 Week 4    33    50
5      DS1 Week 1    22    50
6      DS2 Week 2    42    50
7      DS2 Week 3    13    50
8      DS2 Week 4    17    50
9      DS2 Week 1    50    50
10     DS2 Week 2    32    50
11     DS3 Week 3    20    50
12     DS3 Week 4    20    50
13     DS3 Week 1    41    50
14     DS3 Week 2    45    50
15     DS3 Week 3     9    50
16     DS4 Week 4     6    50
17     DS4 Week 1     8    50
18     DS4 Week 2    14    50
19     DS4 Week 3    20    50
20     DS4 Week 4    36    50
```

In this case, I don't want the count (blue) to show up at all. However, there is still a tiny blob visible. Is it possible to remove that blob (top row, third column) from the plot somehow?

```
# plot
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = week, y = dataset)) +
  geom_count (aes(size=total), colour="lightgrey") +
  geom_count(aes(size=count), colour="cornflowerblue")  +
  scale_size(range = c(0,15), breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,50)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "", x = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)  #invert order
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the missing values *inside* ggplot using `ifelse` and `na.rm = TRUE`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = week, y = dataset)) +
  geom_count(aes(size = total), colour = "lightgrey") +
  geom_count(aes(size = ifelse(count == 0, NA, count)), 
             colour = "cornflowerblue", na.rm = TRUE)  +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 15), breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "", x = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe replace the zero values with `NA` prior to `ggplot`? By default, missing value is removed in `ggplot`.

> #> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(dataset = paste0("DS",rep(1:4, each = 5)),
                week = paste0("Week ",rep(1:4,5)),
                count = c(sample(0:50, 20, replace = TRUE)),
                total = rep(50,20)) 

ggplot(df %>% mutate(count = ifelse(count == 0, NA, count)), 
       aes(x = week, y = dataset)) +
  geom_count(aes(size=total), colour="lightgrey") +
  geom_count(aes(size=count), colour="cornflowerblue")  +
  scale_size(range = c(1,15), breaks=c(1,10,20,30,40,50)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "", x = "") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)
```

[image]